# BottomNavigation selected icon not displayed?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I use the bottom navigation view to display my menu.
when I run the app it's not displaying selected icon and text see below image.(App uses svg(xml) images files)

And TextSize cutting when its length bigger and tab are more than 3 or 4
[See this image for text cutting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur0q8.png)

[image]

Here My Code
MainActivity xml file

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Navigation Menu

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_light"
        android:title="@string/str_home"/>

<item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_medidate"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_meditation_light"
        android:title="@string/str_meditade"/>

<item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_lessions"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_lesson_light"
        android:title="@string/str_lessions"/>

<item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_sleep"
        android:visible="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sleep_light"
        android:title="@string/str_sleep"/>

<item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_cources"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_course_light"
        android:visible="false"
        android:title="@string/str_courses"/>
```

Navigation Listener

```
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_cources -> {
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_lessions -> {
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_medidate -> {
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_sleep -> {
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }
```

Comment: You have to add two drawables one for active state and second for inactive state. Your active drawable colour is white thats why its not showing on selected tab.

Comment: Thanks for your support @Heisenberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a selector for tint icon `selector_navigation.xml`. Use `app:itemIconTint` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/blue" />
<item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"  />
</selector>
```

and set to `BottomNavigationView`

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/darker_gray"
                app:menu="@menu/navigation"
                app:layout_behavior="BottomNavigationBehavior"
                app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector_navigation" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modified text size of selected or unselected tab.Add below code in dimens.xml

```
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size">11sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size">12sp</dimen>
```

Below code for other custom sizes

```
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_item_max_width">168dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_item_min_width">96dp</dimen>       
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_elevation">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height">56dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_icon_size">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_item_max_width">96dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_item_min_width">56dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_margin">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_shadow_height">1dp</dimen>
    <color name="design_bottom_navigation_shadow_color">#14000000</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to return as "true" instead of false on onNavigation click listner

```
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.navigation_home -> {
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_cources -> {
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_lessions -> {
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_medidate -> {
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_sleep -> {
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    true
}
```